# Chrome Extension - Receiving requests in the content script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is there a better way to pass commands between the content script and the popup/background? Right now I'm doing something like this (and it's not maintainable or robust....)

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
    if (request) {
      switch (request.command) {
        case "command1":
            //do stuff
            break;
        case "command2":
            //do stuff
            break;
```

This is in the content script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use Mozilla's [WebExtension polyfill](https://github.com/mozilla/webextension-polyfill)
- Use a class or an object to define the command handlers and a [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) to invoke them.

content.js

```
const API = new Proxy({}, {
  get(target, command) {
    return data => browser.runtime.sendMessage({command, data});
  },
});
```

Using with a Promise:

```
API.foo(123).then(console.log);
```

Using with async/await:

```
async function doSomething() {
  const result = await API.bar(456);
  console.log(result);
}
```

background.js

```
class Commands extends null {
  static foo(data, sender) {
    return data * 2;
  }
  async static bar(data, sender) {
    return (await fetch('https://example.org/json')).json();
  }
}

browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(async ({command, data}, sender) => {
  const handler = Commands.hasOwnProperty(command) && Commands[command];
  return typeof handler === 'function'
         ? handler(data, sender)
         : Promise.reject();
});
```

That was a simplified barebones example without error handling. The same may be applied to extension->content route and you can put this into a separate js that's loaded both in the content script and an extension page. There could be existing js libraries that implement this approach.

Comment: Could you show how the addListener in (background.js) would look if you had to use multiple command classes?

Comment: Depends. You could use inherited classes (with normal non-static methods) with the commands and have the listener check Commands.prototype which will have all the methods. Or you can check each class separately, or in a loop. Or you could use any event emitter/subscriber library (or write your own) and just re-emit the command+data through.

Comment: btw doesn't work for me, command in get passes as an empty object

Comment: Yep, should be fixed now.